# read.abif not found after installing package.

Tags: r

Trying to a get a working version of this:

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/seqinr/docs/read.abif

So in R 3.1.0 I have run:

```
install.packages("seqinr")
fsa <- read.abif("/Users/afrieden/Downloads/aflp/AFLP_sample_A01_001_2004-11-22.fsa")
```

But I am getting the error:

```
Error: could not find function "read.abif"
```

Even though it should be in this package.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably the FAQ item about not loading the package.

Comment: Expanding on BondedDust's comment, have you loaded the library with `library(seqinr)` or `require(seqinr)`?